# ¿Qué significa "voces" en esta frase de "El Burlador de Sevilla"?

Tags: significado, sustantivos, significado-en-contexto

En la jornada primera [*El burlador de Sevilla*](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/El_burlador_de_Sevilla/Acto_I)​ de Tirso de Molina, don Pedro dice:

> ¿En tu cuarto, gran señor
> voces? ¿Quién la causa fue?

Significa *[voces](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/voz#Espa%C3%B1ol)* algo como ruido?

Comment: Está haciendo una elipsis del verbo *escuchar*, *oír* o completalo con cualquier sinónimo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la escena anterior, el rey llama a un guardia diciendo "¡Ah de mi guarda! Prendé a este hombre". Entonces llegan el guardia y Pedro Tenorio.

Lo que dice Pedro Tenorio al llegar significa entonces, más o menos, *"Gran señor, he oído gritos en tu cuarto..."*

Corresponde a la definición #7 que pones en tu link. En el diccionario de la RAE sale así:

> **[voz](https://dle.rae.es/voz?m=form)**
>
> 4. f. Grito, voz esforzada y levantada. U. m. en pl.

La abreviación "U. m. en pl." nos dice que, con este significado, se usa más habitualmente el plural "voces" que el singular "voz".